# How to modify url in a django get request

Tags: django, url, get, paginator

I have a web page which displays some data (with get parameters to filter in the view) and I use a pagination.

To go through the data i use a link to change the page in the paginator :

```
<li class="paginator-data"><a href="{{ request.get_full_path }}?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next</a></li>
```

Here is the view :

```
@login_required
def search_and_export(request):

    # initialisation
    page_obj = Tree.objects.all()
    
    # FORM
    if request.method == 'GET':
        
        ## Here I get GET parameters or a default value like 
        
        data = str(request.GET.get('data', 1))
        page = str(request.GET.get('page', 1))
        

        ## creating a queryDict

        querydict = QueryDict('data='  data + '&page=' + page)
        big_request_form    = BigRequestForm(querydict)
        
        if big_request_form.is_valid():
            
            # Getting data from front endda
            data    = big_request_form.cleaned_data['data']
            # Extracting QuerySet
            page_obj    = filtering_function(data)

        
        paginator   = Paginator(page_obj,25)

        
        page_obj = paginator.get_page(page)
        page_obj.adjusted_elided_pages = paginator.get_elided_page_range(number = page, on_each_side=1, on_ends=1)

    else:
        big_request_form = BigRequestForm()
    
    # return values

    context = {
        'big_request_form'      : big_request_form,
        'page_obj'              : page_obj,
    }
    
    return render(request, 'filtered_stats.html', context)
```

Here is the problem : url looks like that after browsing a few pages :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/?data=x&page=2&page=3&page=4&page=5&page=6
```

The view is working well (It displays me the last page) but I got this ugly link.

I tried something like that :

```
request.GET.get = querydict
```

(with querydict a QueryDict object with only one page data)
But It didn't work. I also thought of parsing data in the template but maybe there is a better way.

Comment: Please share the view.

Comment: Ok I did it @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do in HTML template is to get current URL. But actually you don't have to do it - relative path can be used instead. So just remove it:

```
<li class="paginator-data"><a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next</a></li>
```

The browser knows current URL and will use `href` attribute relative to it.

**UPD**
alternative - to keep other parameters in the URL is to construct "next URL" inside the view and pass it in context as `next_url`.

I.e. something like so:

In **views**:

```
 next_url = request.get_full_path()
 next_url.replace(f'page={current}', f'page={page_obj.next_page_number}')
 context['next_url'] = next_url
```

In template:

```
<li class="paginator-data"><a href="{{ next_url }}">Next</a></li>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
But I need to have data for my filtering query (I edited my post with a overview of my view). So i can't delete {{ request.get_full_path }}.

Comment: @antoine_d, see update in the answer

Comment: Nice thanks, good idea I will edit the question !